# c++, using enable_if along with existing template class?

Tags: c++, templates

I have existing template class A,B that cannot be changed.

```
template<class T> 
struct A{static void F(){}};
template<int I>
struct B{};
```

I want to specialize `A` only when `T` is `B<I>` and `1<=I<=5`.

If A can be changed, it would be like the following :

```
template<class T,class = void>//added second param 
struct A{static void F(){}};
template<int I>
struct B{};

template<int I>
struct A< B<I>, std::enable_if_t<(1<=I&&I<=5)> >{static void F(){}};

int main(){
  A<B<0>>::F();//call origin ver
  A<B<1>>::F();//call specialized ver
  A<B<10>>::F();//call origin ver
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: add `static_assert` inside `A<T>::F` definition?

Comment: At worst, 1<= I <= 5 is only 5 specializations...

Comment: @user3365922, it simply failed compiling

Comment: What compiler are you using? It works here: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/KZR6dk

Comment: @SimonKraemer The questions states that `A` can't be modified. OP is aware that the presented code works, but it's not possible to use it in his case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could redirect the specialization into inheriting from a conditional implementation

```
template<class T> 
struct A{
    static void F() { std::cout << "default\n"; }
};

template<int I>
struct B{};

struct tag{};

template<int I>
struct ABImpl {
    static void F() { std::cout << "specialized for " << I << '\n'; }
};

template<int I>
struct A<B<I>> : std::conditional_t<1 <= I && I <= 5, ABImpl<I>, A<tag>> {};
```

The `tag` is a dummy that' simply used for grabbing a default implementation without risk of conflict.

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb92b20cd22fa8c8)

Answer (score 0):

Add one layer of indirection.

```
template <class T>
struct SpecializedA {
    //... specialized implementation
};

template<class T,class = void>//added second param 
struct MyA_impl{
    using type = A<T>;
};

template<int I>
struct MyA_impl< B<I>, std::enable_if_t<(1<=I&&I<=5)> >{
    using type = SpecializedA<B<I>>;
};

template <typename T>
using MyA = typename MyA_impl<T>::type;
```

With that we get

```
MyA<B<0>> == A<B<0>>  
MyA<B<1>> == SpecializedA<B<1>>  
MyA<int> == A<int>
```